# Kendo Scheduler can't set end in save event

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to programatically change the `start` and `end` dates when the Scheduler's `save` event is fired.

I'm using moment.js to do the manipulation. This is working for the `start` value, but it won't update `end`

This is what I'm doing:

```
 var start = moment(e.event.start).hours(6).minutes(30).seconds(0),
 end = start.clone().add(8, 'hours');
 if (e.event.isAllDay) {
     e.event.set('start', start.toDate() );
     e.event.set('end', end.toDate() );
}
```

This sets the start time of `all day` events to 06:30:00, but the end time isn't updated and is always 00:00:00

Any ideas why I can't set the end time in this way?